# copying value from one table to another table using dropdwon list using sql and php

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

i have 2 tables "cities" and "customers" with same row "city_name", i want the customer to select a city from dropdown list that Fetch its values from "cities" and store his city choice at "customers"

what i have been getting at "costumers" is a rows of 0's instead of city names, here is my code:

```
$query_2 = "SELECT city_name FROM cities";
   $result_2 = mysql_query($query_2) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
   $i_2 = 0;
       while($rows_2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_2))
            {
              $city_name[$i_2] = $rows_2['city_name'];
              $i_2++;
            }
    $total_elmt_2 = count($city_name);
```

^ here to create the list

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {

        $city_name = $_POST['city_name'];

      {
```

^ this is to post the value

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `customers`( `city_name`)"
        ." VALUES ('$city_name')",$conn)
```

^ this is my query

```
<label>city <small>(required)</small></label>
            <select id="city_name" name="city_name">
                              <option>Select</option>
                                    <?php 
                             for($j=0;$j<$total_elmt_2;$j++)
                                   {
                                ?><option><?php 
                                  echo $city_name[$j];
                                    ?></option><?php
                                           }
                                               ?>
                                       </select>
```

^ this is the dropdown list where the customer pick up his city

i hope can find someone to tell me where i went wrong in this code :(

Comment: You're using the same variable `$city_name` for the POST parameter and the array fetched from the SQL.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: Don't use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: sorry but i do not know how to use var_dump($_POST);

Comment: You just put it in the script, and it will show up on the result page of the form.

Comment: If you don't know about `var_dump` or `print_r`, how do you normally debug your scripts?

Comment: just run it at phpmyadmin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the data type of your `city_name` column of your `customers` table set to `varchar`, `text` or something related to string?

You forgot semi-colon (`;`) after you execute your query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `customers`( `city_name`)"
    ." VALUES ('$city_name')", $conn);
                                     ^
```

And an opening bracket (`{`) after declaring your `$city_name` variable? Replace it with a closing bracket (`}`).

Does some of the data coming from `customers` table might have the chance of having `'`? Use [`*_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) before inserting data to your database.

```
$city_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["city_name"]);
```

Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) extension instead of [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` extension.

Comment: If an option doesn't have a value, it defaults to the content.

Comment: YES thank you so much! its error in the data type in my database, i wouldn't have noticed